# How to get data from two classes that are many-to-many, in the same edit form?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, controller, many-to-many

I am working with two classes that have a relationship many-to-many. I insert data in both tables, the relationship is usually registered in JoinTable. My question is, how to display the data from both tables in the same form?

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class RecipeController {

@Autowired
private ReceitaService receitaService;  

 @RequestMapping(value = "/novaReceita.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createRecipes(@ModelAttribute("Receita") Receita receita, BindingResult resultReceita, 
                            @ModelAttribute("Tag") Tag tag, BindingResult resultTag, @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map) {


    receita.getTag().add(tag);    
    receitaService.addReceita(receita);

    map.put("receita", receita);

    map.put("receitaList", receitaService.getAllReceita());

    return "listRecipes";

}
```

Here is where I am having problems because I can only show data for a single table.

```
  public String editForm(@PathVariable("id") int id, ModelMap map) {

    map.addAttribute("receita", receitaService.getReceita(id));

    return "updateRecipes";
}
```

Finally, the JSP page to display the data entered:

```
<c:url var="url" value="/receita/${receita.id}"/>   
<form:form action="${url}" method="GET" commandName="receita">
            <table width=80% > 
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>ID </strong></td>
                    <td><form:input path="id" disabled="true" class="input-small"/></td>                         
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Title </strong></td>
                    <td><form:input path="titulo" class="input-xlarge"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign=top><strong>Desc probl</strong></td>
                    <td><form:textarea path="desc_prob" class="input-xlarge" rows="3" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign=top><strong>Desc soluc</strong></td>
                    <td><form:textarea path="desc_soluc" class="input-xlarge" rows="6" /></td>
                </tr>                    
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Tag</strong></td>
                    <td> <form:input path="tag" disabled="true" class="input-small"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>    
        </form:form>
```

What is missing to be able to show the data from both tables?
Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single column/property you can use `<form:input/>`
For Many to One you can use `<form:select/>`
For One to Many you can use `<form:select multiple='true'>`
In your case, you have to select a single ID first for the one side of the relationship which is `receita` and then display all the tags in that receita, so i think it counts as One to Many at that point. So in your case, try to use this tag:
`<form:select path="tag" multiple="true"/>`